# Subcaption package error, even without the use of the subfigure package

Tags: floats, subfloats, subcaption

I have read countless instructions on how to use the subcaption package, and tried several examples. Each time I get two types of errors, which I will post further down. This is my premable:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, oneside]{Thesis} % Paper size, default font size and one-    sided paper
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00A0}{~}
\graphicspath{{./Figures/}} % Specifies the directory where pictures are stored
\usepackage[backend=bibtex, natbib, style=authoryear,maxbibnames=9, doi=false,    url=true, isbn=false]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{norsk}{bibliography = {References},}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{mdwlist}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\usepackage{paralist}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\newcommand{\Qline}[1]{\noindent\rule{#1}{0.6pt}}
```

This is the current caption code:

```
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{E:/Masteroppgaven/TeXhis/Figures/QuickRight}
            \caption{Original Prototype}
            \label{fig:QRight}
    \end{subfigure}%
    ~ 
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{E:/Masteroppgaven/TeXhis/Figures/QuickLeft}
            \caption{Second Iteration}
            \label{fig:QLeft}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{Quick Selection}\label{fig:QSelect}
\end{figure}
```

Finally, these are the error messages that I am given.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\caption\subcaption.sty:48: 
Package subcaption Error: This package can't be used in cooperation [\endinput}{}]

E:\Masteroppgaven\TeXhis\Chapters\UseOfTheNovelDesignPrinciples.tex:28: 
Missing number, treated as zero. [\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}]

E:\Masteroppgaven\TeXhis\Chapters\UseOfTheNovelDesignPrinciples.tex:28: 
Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted). [\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}]
```

Does anyone have any idea of how I can solve this issue? The reason I added the preamble is that most other people have stated that the subcaption package can't be used together with the subfigure package, but as you can see I do not add it to my Thesis.tex

Comment: Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: I provided an answer below, but I want to confirm my suspicion. Could you please provide a link to the class `Thesis.cls` (if it's not publicly available, you can uploaded elsewhere and provide the link)?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Seeing the error message, what happens is that your document class `Thesis` internally loads `subfigure` and this produces the clash, since `subcaption` and `subfigure` cannot be used simultaneously. Search the file `Thesis.cls` for a line

```
\RequirePackage{subfigure}
```

and comment it out.

Comment: That was exactly it. Thank you! If only the error messages would reflect where the conflict occured, this would have been so much easier.

Comment: This totally works. For people who might be visiting here again, I tried this with bmvc2k class for British Machine Vision Conference paper. Worked like a charm. Many thanks!